# trying to get the username to create dynamic pages in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla2.5

After the user logs into my site, I want to store the username in a session variable, so that I can use that information in another dynamic page depending on which user that is logged in,

How do I accomplish this.

Comment: I've just made some pretty massive edits to your question In the hopes that it doesn't get closed fast because it looked like a "give me the codes" question.  If this edit is unwelcome, you have the ability to roll it back

Comment: thanks, I`m just trying to understand where I need to put the code to get the user name into a session variable.

Answer (score 0):

If your users are logging into Joomla and you need the username in a Joomla file such as a template file you can do the following:

```
$user = $JFactory::getUser();
if (!$user->guest) {
    $username = $user->username;
}

if (!empty($username)) {
    echo $username;
}
```